# How to update the most recent record based on a timestamp - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Hi everyone i tried to this to no avail in regards to efficiently updating the most recent record in postgres.
 Example showing below

```
created table instructions 
{
  uuid uuid,
  type text,
  status text,
  owner text,
  created_at timestamp
}
```

I tried something like this but no luck

```
update table instructions
set status = status
where uuid = uuid
order by created_at desc
limit 1;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? This

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a limit with an update, one thing you can do is use a CTE:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2cd45704599069a963db9046c8b3d26d

[this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1) on a different stack exchange explains it quite well.

Comment: thanks for the response and i checked out the example. But i have a question what if it's based on the most recent `type`? such that types are only of 3 such as `Pass`, `Fail`, and `Average` and you have to update only the most recent type `Average` of a particular `uuid` intsruction?

Comment: thanks a ton i figured your fiddle and the post made it clear. Awesome

Comment: awesome! Glad I could help